# Prime finding - some array values getting overwritten?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have written a sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, but i have a strange bug that I cant figure out.  (Editor's note: this is not a sieve; it uses trial division to test each number for being prime.)

This program asks a user to input a number, then the program will output that number of primes to the screen. **The program prints all primes correctly except after 11, where it will print 3 garbage numbers and skip the number 13, and then it will proceed with the correct number of primes from 17 onwards**. Below is a sample output for 20 primes.

```
> Enter number of primes:
20....
prime number:            1
prime number:            2
prime number:            3
prime number:            5
prime number:            7
prime number:           11
prime number:    538976288
prime number:    909588792
prime number:      3291447
prime number:           17
prime number:           19
prime number:           23
prime number:           29
prime number:           31
prime number:           37
prime number:           41
prime number:           43
prime number:           47
prime number:           53
prime number:           59
```

These numbers are stored in an array, and in sieve.asm i have put a label called "PrintLoop2" which i used to look at every value in the array and i can see 13 listed there and no garbage with it, so i am not sure why this is happening.

Sieve.asm is the main program, genprimes.asm creates the prime numbers and puts them on the stack, and the other files are for I/O.

---

**sieve.asm:**

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h
EXTERN GenPrimes2:PROC
PUBLIC genPrimes
.STACK 4096                 ; reserve 4096-byte stack
.DATA                       ; reserve storage for data

count    DWORD   ?
sieve    BYTE    10000 DUP(1)
string   BYTE    40 DUP (?)
prompt1  BYTE    "Enter number of primes: ", 0
prompt2  BYTE    "prime number: ", 0
prompt3  BYTE    ", ", 0
primenum DWORD    11 DUP (?), 0
prime    BYTE     11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE

genPrimes   PROC
           ; push   ebp                  ; save base pointer
           ; mov    ebp, esp             ; establish stack frame
           ; push   ebx
            ; CODE
            call GenPrimes2 ;call function in genprimes.asm to push primes to stack

            sub esp, 4    ;move esp down
            sub esp, 4    ;esp points to first value

            mov ebx, 4 ; counter
            mov ecx, 0 ; index register to hold value of esp that will be put into primenum array


            loopArray:         ;this loop fills primenum with all primes put on the stack in genprimes.asm
                    mov ecx, [esp]
                    sub esp, 4
                    mov primenum[ebx], ecx
                    add ebx, 4
                    cmp ebx, 2200
            jb  loopArray

                mov ebx, 4
                mov eax, 0
                ;This loop is for debug purposes only, i want to see if the array primenum has the value 13, which is does
                ;because i can see it get copied into ecx. However, i get garbage in my output where 13 should be.
                PrintLoop2:             
                    mov ecx, primenum[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
                    add ebx, 4
                    cmp ebx, 400
                jb  PrintLoop2

                mov ebx, 4
                mov eax, 0

                add esp,2204  ;move esp back to return address
                ret                         ;exit genPrimes
genPrimes    ENDP
_sieve  PROC                            ; start of sieve program code
      input   prompt1, string, 40       ; read ASCII characters
      call  genPrimes
                atod string ; convert to integer the number of primes the user entered
                mov edx, 0

                ;this loop will print all the non-zero values stored in the array primenum, i have set all non-primes to 0's so that only
                ;they will be printed
                PrintLoop:
                mov ecx, primenum[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
                cmp primenum[ebx], 0
                jne printPrime
                
                add ebx, 4
                jmp  PrintLoop

                printPrime:
                dtoa prime, ecx ;convert the prime number to a string for printing
                output  prompt2, prime       ; output label and sum
                add ebx, 4
                inc edx
                cmp edx, eax
                jb  PrintLoop


      mov   eax, 0          ; exit with return code 0
      ret

_sieve  ENDP

END
```

**genprimes.asm:**

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT


.STACK 4096                 
n=550
.data
    prime DWORD n DUP(?)

.code
GenPrimes2  PROC
mov ebx, 4
mov ecx, 0
loopArray:
    inc ecx
    mov prime[ebx], ecx
    add ebx, 4
    cmp ecx, n
jb  loopArray

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 2
mov edx, 0

mov ecx,3

sieve_loop:

    cmp eax,ebx
    je skip

    mov edx, 0 ;zero out remainder
    div  ebx
    cmp edx,0 ; if remainder 0, not a prime
    je    NotPrime ;Jump if is a factor, since it cant be prime

; compare eax with n, if equal increment ebx
    cmp ecx,n
    jge    incrementEbx

;  compare ebx with n, if equal end sieve
    cmp ebx, n
    je sieve_end

    inc ecx
    mov eax, ecx

jmp sieve_loop

skip:
inc eax
jmp sieve_loop


NotPrime:
    mov eax, ecx ; store count in eax
    imul ecx, 4
    mov prime[ecx],0
    mov ecx, eax
    inc ecx ; increment ecx count
    inc eax ; increment eax divisor
    jmp sieve_loop

incrementEbx:
inc ebx
mov eax, 3 ; dividend
mov ecx, 3 ; counter

jmp sieve_loop


sieve_end:
    mov ebx, 4
    mov eax, 0
; *************  Add break point on print loop, ecx will be loading with primes and 0's  ********************
; *************  All non-prime numbers have been changed to a 0                          ********************


    PrintLoop:
    mov ecx, prime[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
    push   ecx
    add ebx, 4
    cmp ebx, 2200
    jb  PrintLoop

        add esp,2196
    mov   eax, 0          ; exit with return code 0
    ret
GenPrimes2 ENDP
END
```

**io.asm:**

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
PUBLIC wtoaproc, atowproc, dtoaproc, atodproc

.CODE

; wtoaproc(source, dest)
; convert integer (source) to string of 6 characters at given destination address
; source integer passed as a doubleword, but only low-order word is processed
wtoaproc    PROC
            push   ebp                  ; save base pointer
            mov    ebp, esp             ; establish stack frame
            push   eax                  ; Save registers
            push   ebx
            push   ecx
            push   edx
            push   edi
            pushfd                     ; save flags

            mov    eax, [ebp+8]        ; first parameter (source integer)
            and    eax, 0ffffh         ; mask high-order word
            mov    edi, [ebp+12]       ; second parameter (dest offset)
ifSpecW:    cmp    ax,8000h            ; special case -32,768?
            jne    EndIfSpecW          ; if not, then normal case
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi],'-'  ; manually put in ASCII codes
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+1],'3'  ;   for -32,768
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+2],'2'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+3],'7'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+4],'6'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+5],'8'
            jmp    ExitIToA            ; done with special case
EndIfSpecW:

            push eax                   ; save source number

            mov    al,' '              ; put blanks in
            mov    ecx,5               ;   first five
            cld                        ;   bytes of
            rep stosb                  ;   destination field

            pop    eax                 ; restore source number
            mov    cl,' '              ; default sign (blank for +)
IfNegW:     cmp    ax,0                ; check sign of number
            jge    EndIfNegW           ; skip if not negative
            mov    cl,'-'              ; sign for negative number
            neg    ax                  ; number in AX now >= 0
EndIfNegW:

            mov    bx,10               ; divisor

WhileMoreW: mov    dx,0                ; extend number to doubleword
            div    bx                  ; divide by 10
            add    dl,'0'              ; convert remainder to character
            mov    [edi],dl            ; put character in string
            dec    edi                 ; move forward to next position
            cmp    ax,0                ; check quotient
            jnz    WhileMoreW          ; continue if quotient not zero

            mov    [edi],cl            ; insert blank or "-" for sign

ExitIToA:   popfd                      ; restore flags and registers
            pop    edi
            pop    edx
            pop    ecx
            pop    ebx
            pop    eax
            pop    ebp
            ret                        ;exit
wtoaproc    ENDP

; dtoaproc(source, dest)
; convert double (source) to string of 11 characters at given destination address
dtoaproc    PROC   NEAR32
            push   ebp                 ; save base pointer
            mov    ebp, esp            ; establish stack frame
            push   eax                 ; Save registers
            push   ebx                 ;   used by
            push   ecx                 ;   procedure
            push   edx
            push   edi
            pushfd                      ; save flags

            mov    eax, [ebp+8]         ; first parameter (source double)
            mov    edi, [ebp+12]        ; second parameter (dest addr)
ifSpecialD: cmp    eax,80000000h        ; special case -2,147,483,648?
            jne    EndIfSpecialD        ; if not, then normal case
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi],'-'   ; manually put in ASCII codes
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+1],'2' ;   for -2,147,483,648
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+2],'1'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+3],'4'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+4],'7'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+5],'4'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+6],'8'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+7],'3'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+8],'6'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+9],'4'
            mov    BYTE PTR [edi+10],'8'
            jmp    ExitDToA            ; done with special case
EndIfSpecialD:

            push   eax                 ; save source number

            mov    al,' '              ; put blanks in
            mov    ecx,10              ;   first ten
            cld                        ;   bytes of
            rep stosb                  ;   destination field

            pop    eax                 ; copy source number
            mov    cl,' '              ; default sign (blank for +)
IfNegD:     cmp    eax,0               ; check sign of number
            jge    EndIfNegD           ; skip if not negative
            mov    cl,'-'              ; sign for negative number
            neg    eax                 ; number in EAX now >= 0
EndIfNegD:

            mov    ebx,10              ; divisor

WhileMoreD: mov    edx,0               ; extend number to doubleword
            div    ebx                 ; divide by 10
            add    dl,30h              ; convert remainder to character
            mov    [edi],dl            ; put character in string
            dec    edi                 ; move forward to next position
            cmp    eax,0               ; check quotient
            jnz    WhileMoreD          ; continue if quotient not zero

            mov    [edi],cl            ; insert blank or "-" for sign

ExitDToA:   popfd                      ; restore flags and registers
            pop    edi
            pop    edx
            pop    ecx
            pop    ebx
            pop    eax
            pop    ebp
            ret                        ;exit
dtoaproc    ENDP

; atowproc(source)
; Procedure to scan data segment starting at source address, interpreting
; ASCII characters as an word-size integer value which is returned in AX.

; Leading blanks are skipped.  A leading - or + sign is acceptable.
; Digit(s) must immediately follow the sign (if any).
; Memory scan is terminated by any non-digit.

; No error checking is done. If the number is outside the range for a
; signed word, then the return value is undefined.

atowproc    PROC
            push   ebp                 ; save base pointer
            mov    ebp, esp            ; establish stack frame
            sub    esp, 2              ; local space for sign
            push   ebx                 ; Save registers
            push   edx
            push   esi
            pushfd                     ; save flags

            mov    esi,[ebp+8]         ; get parameter (source addr)

WhileBlankW:cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],' '  ; space?
            jne    EndWhileBlankW      ; exit if not
            inc    esi                 ; increment character pointer
            jmp    WhileBlankW         ; and try again
EndWhileBlankW:

            mov    ax,1                ; default sign multiplier
IfPlusW:    cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'+'  ; leading + ?
            je     SkipSignW           ; if so, skip over
IfMinusW:   cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'-'  ; leading - ?
            jne    EndIfSignW          ; if not, save default +
            mov    ax,-1               ; -1 for minus sign
SkipSignW:  inc    esi                 ; move past sign
EndIfSignW:

            mov    [ebp-2],ax          ; save sign multiplier
            mov    ax,0                ; number being accumulated

WhileDigitW:cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'0'  ; next character >= '0'
            jnge   EndWhileDigitW      ; exit if not
            cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'9'  ; next character <= '9'
            jnle   EndWhileDigitW      ; not a digit if bigger than '9'
            imul   ax,10               ; multiply old number by 10
            mov    bl,[esi]            ; ASCII character to BL
            and    bx,000Fh            ; convert to single-digit integer
            add    ax,bx               ; add to sum
            inc    esi                 ; increment character pointer
            jmp    WhileDigitW         ; go try next character
EndWhileDigitW:

; if value is < 8000h, multiply by sign
            cmp    ax,8000h            ; 8000h?
            jnb    endIfMaxW           ; skip if not
            imul   WORD PTR [ebp-2]    ; make signed number
endIfMaxW:

            popfd                      ; restore flags
            pop    esi                 ; restore registers
            pop    edx
            pop    ebx
            mov    esp, ebp            ; delete local variable space
            pop    ebp
            ret                        ; exit
atowproc    ENDP

; atodproc(source)
; Procedure to scan data segment starting at source address, interpreting
; ASCII characters as an doubleword-size integer value which is returned in EAX.

; Leading blanks are skipped.  A leading - or + sign is acceptable.
; Digit(s) must immediately follow the sign (if any).
; Memory scan is terminated by any non-digit.

; No error checking is done. If the number is outside the range for a
; signed word, then the return value is undefined.

atodproc    PROC
            push   ebp                 ; save base pointer
            mov    ebp, esp            ; establish stack frame
            sub    esp, 4              ; local space for sign
            push   ebx                 ; Save registers
            push   edx
            push   esi
            pushfd                     ; save flags

            mov    esi,[ebp+8]         ; get parameter (source addr)

WhileBlankD:cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],' '  ; space?
            jne    EndWhileBlankD      ; exit if not
            inc    esi                 ; increment character pointer
            jmp    WhileBlankD         ; and try again
EndWhileBlankD:

            mov    eax,1               ; default sign multiplier
IfPlusD:    cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'+'  ; leading + ?
            je     SkipSignD           ; if so, skip over
IfMinusD:   cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'-'  ; leading - ?
            jne    EndIfSignD          ; if not, save default +
            mov    eax,-1              ; -1 for minus sign
SkipSignD:  inc    esi                 ; move past sign
EndIfSignD:

            mov    [ebp-4],eax         ; save sign multiplier
            mov    eax,0               ; number being accumulated

WhileDigitD:cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'0'  ; compare next character to '0'
            jl     EndWhileDigitD      ; not a digit if smaller than '0'
            cmp    BYTE PTR [esi],'9'  ; compare to '9'
            jg     EndWhileDigitD      ; not a digit if bigger than '9'
            imul   eax,10              ; multiply old number by 10
            mov    bl,[esi]            ; ASCII character to BL
            and    ebx,0000000Fh       ; convert to single-digit integer
            add    eax,ebx             ; add to sum
            inc    esi                 ; increment character pointer
            jmp    WhileDigitD         ; go try next character
EndWhileDigitD:

; if value is < 80000000h, multiply by sign
            cmp    eax,80000000h       ; 80000000h?
            jnb    endIfMaxD           ; skip if not
            imul   DWORD PTR [ebp-4]   ; make signed number
endIfMaxD:

            popfd                      ; restore flags
            pop    esi                 ; restore registers
            pop    edx
            pop    ebx
            mov    esp, ebp            ; delete local variable space
            pop    ebp
            ret                        ; exit
atodproc    ENDP

            END
```

**framework.c**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char buf[255];
static char inputLabel[255];

// disables warning for strcpy use
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

void getInput(char* inputPrompt, char* result, int maxChars)
{
    puts(inputPrompt);
    gets(buf);
    buf[maxChars - 1] = '\0';
    strcpy(result,buf);
    return;
}

void showOutput(char* outputLabel, char* outputString)
{
    printf("%s %s\n",outputLabel,outputString);
}

int sieve(void);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONIN$" , "rb", stdin);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "wb", stdout);

    return sieve();
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting a watchpoint on the memory address where the value is stored?  Also, your code is very long and confusing.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes doesn't require trial division at all, just *addition*.  (And squaring to start crossing out candidates at `i^2`, because earlier iterations of the outer loop have already eliminated multiples of `i` up to `i^2`)  But you're using `div` for something, and comments don't really explain it.

Comment: You also have a weird `imul` by 4.  But I think that's for indexing by dwords instead of bytes.  (Totally silly; you should just use an array of 0 / non-zero bytes, or even bits.  And if you do use dwords, `mov primes[ecx*4], 0` to take advantage of scaled-index addressing modes.  Or use `shl ecx,2` to scale by 4.

Comment: It's good to show all your code, but you should really use a debugger to narrow it down to *which* code is not doing what you want it to.  See http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ for why this isn't ideal.  (I didn't downvote myself yet, but this is *way* too much code to run in my head and find the problem buried somewhere in that giant pile.  There's a weird `atowproc` in there that uses `word` operand-size for something.  I don't think you're even converting strings to integers at all, though.)

Comment: I know genprimes.asm works because i can get all the values i need off of the stack and into the array "primenum" in seive.asm. I can look at all the values in that array in the loop called "PrintLoop2". I have not tried watching that particular memory address because i dont know how and didnt know you can do that. I only know how to watch registers. I am very much a novice assembly programmer. I will try and research how to find which address that is and how to watch it, that might solve my problem. I am using Visual Studio so hopefully thats a feature of the software.

Comment: Yeah, most debuggers have a watchpoint to see when memory changes.  It's useful for C/C++ debugging too, to see when a variable changes, so it's not like it's an asm-specific feature.  Of course you can just manually watch it while single-stepping to see when the value at that address is overwritten.  (And if that never happens, then it was corrupted some time after it was copied out of there.)

Comment: As a side note, one is not a prime number.

Comment: I figured out watch points, and when i call "dtoa prime, ecx ;" it overwrites a value in the address: 0x00DF431B, which is where the number 13 is stored. This is strange to me because i popped the values off the stack and into the array. Didnt know memory could over lap in other places like that. Guess my next task is to figure out how and why that function is writing to that memory location.

Comment: Your code builds your array on the stack, right?  Memory below the current value of `esp` will get clobbered by function calls, and can even be asynchronously clobbered by signal handlers.  (You have a ton of code, but I think I saw something about using the stack for the array).  Or is your string output buffer overlapping with your array?  Your `dtoa` function has some inefficient code for sure, like the separate byte stores for the one special case.  The div loop is ok, but strangely uses `cmp eax,0` instead of `test eax,eax`, and `mov edx,0` instead of `xor edx,edx`.

Comment: @grantmiller: I left out the `[sieve-of-eratosthenes]` tag when cleaning up this question, because I don't think it *is* a real sieve.  It looks more like an array that records the results of trial division.  There's definitely trial-division going on, and I don't see any code that increments by a stride to cross out multiples of that number in the rest of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Several buffer overflows.

> primenum DWORD    11 DUP (?), 0

Although *primenum* has only 12 dwords available, your program writes 549 dwords in this array!

> prime DWORD n DUP(?)

The loop that initializes this array writes 1 dword beyond it! Verify it.

### Returning values on the stack.

> ```
>  mov  ebx, 4
> PrintLoop:
>  mov  ecx, prime[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
>  push ecx
>  add  ebx, 4
>  cmp  ebx, 2200
>  jb   PrintLoop
>
>  add  esp,2196
>
>  mov  eax, 0          ; exit with return code 0
>  ret
> ```

First you push 549 dwords on the stack and then by executing `add esp, 2196` you effectively say that you don't care about them anymore.
Values that are to be returned via the stack must stay **above the stackpointer**.
You can simply temporarily remove the return address and then, before `ret`, put it back.

```
 pop  eax             ; Temporarily remove return address

 mov  ebx, 4
PrintLoop:
 mov  ecx, prime[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
 push ecx
 add  ebx, 4
 cmp  ebx, 2200
 jb   PrintLoop

 push eax             ; Put back return address

 xor  eax, eax        ; exit with return code 0
 ret
```

Of course this effects how the caller needs to process these values.

```
 call GenPrimes2 ;call function in genprimes.asm to push primes to stack

 lea  ebp, [esp + 2196] ; EBP points beyond first value

 xor  ebx, ebx
loopArray:  ; fills primenum with all primes pushed in genprimes.asm
 add  ebx, 4
 sub  ebp, 4
 mov  ecx, [ebp]
 mov  primenum[ebx], ecx
 cmp  ebp, esp
 ja   loopArray

 mov ebx, 4
 mov eax, 0

 add  esp, 2196  ; Permanently remove results from stack
 ret
```

---

> ```
> ; compare eax with n, if equal increment ebx
> cmp  ecx,n
> jge  incrementEbx
> ```

Please notice that the comment doesn't match the code (`eax` vs `ecx`).

---

> ```
> mov ecx, primenum[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
> cmp primenum[ebx], 0
> jne printPrime
> ```

Here's an obvious optimization. Since you just loaded the number in `ECX`, it would be better to perform the test on the register.

```
mov  ecx, primenum[ebx] ; Prime numbers are the non-zeros in this Array
test ecx, ecx
jnz  printPrime
```